# Google Chrome Freezes ALL the time

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I'm running the most recent version of Google Chrome. I have had this computer for three weeks now with no problems, now today it just WON'T work for me. I am running windows 8 with a machine that can more than handle Chrome. It keeps freezing up literally every five seconds then it unfreezes. I cannot click links or scroll, but I can switch tabs. I have  tried several things.

1. Uninstalling Google Chrome
2. Reinstalling Chrome but not logging in
3. Deleting All plugins including Flash
4. Creating a new user and accessing chrome from there

This is insanely frustrating and would be forever indebted to whomever helped me solve this problem. I cannot imagine what it is.

Thank  you in advance!

Comment: 1. Update graphics drivers 2. Try disabling built-in Flash plugin and installing from Adobe's site 3. Try disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem a while ago, frustrating as all hell. Turned out to be driver related - updating my chipset and GFX hcard drivers solved the freezing.

Although I've also ran into cases where chrome froze up because I had Flash installed on the PC. Chrome has flash built in so I think there was a compatibility issue. I would update your drivers and if that fails, remove flash from the PC.

Comment: GFX hcard are graphics card drivers right?

Comment: Yes, your graphics card drivers.

Comment: Ok I just update both of of them and restarted my computer - no luck.

Comment: Okay. type in "chrome://plugins" into your browser. Make sure none are loaded and if they are, temporarily disable them. I know you said you did this but double check anyways

Comment: Yes, I just checked - everything is disabled

Comment: Everything is disabled @scandalist